# Flutter: Launch my other application from flutter application and get some data back

Tags: flutter

Using flutter to launch other applications on both the platform (Android/iOS). I know we can use **[url_laucher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)** to launch applications like Gmail or Google map.

Can it also be used for launching my own application?

If "YES", is it possible to get some data back from my other application to flutter application?

If "NO" then is there any other way to do this. **My goal is to get the data (like a simple string) back from my other app.**

**NOTE**: Constraint is that I have to use flutter Widgets or packages and not touch the native directories.

Answer (score 0):

`Yes`, you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to launch your own application provided your application has appropriate url schemes defined.

`No`, you cannot get back any data by launching an application with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

---

Is there a way to achieve this only using flutter widgets and existing plugins?

`Yes`, only on android. There seems to be a [flutter_share](https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share) plugin that allows you to share data to other apps and receive data shared by other apps.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank for the reply. flutter_share uses the native Android code to get this done. I was searching for something which does not use native support.

Comment: You cannot communicate between two different application without using native code. That's not possible in flutter. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion. Given a post on medium for the same. https://medium.com/@ranaranvijaysingh9/share-data-between-two-applications-flutter-and-android-1bb6e2573103